# Appending a link in JavaScript for mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I tried searching for my problem, but couldn't find a solution. Sorry if this is already posted.

I have a dynamically created href link using append, but it does not work on mobile Safari and mobile Chrome (other than ipad). The link works fine on all desktop browsers I have tested or if I choose "Request desktop site" on a mobile device. This is what I am doing:

I am using append to create some elements and one of them contains my link. The information is simply taken from a json array.

HTML:

```
<ul id="structure"></ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function createStructure(i){

    $(structure).append($('<ul> \
    <li data-type="media" data-url=\"' + properties[i].image + '\"data-target="_blank"></li> \
    <li data-thumbnail-path=\"' + properties[i].thumbnail + '\"></li> \
    <li data-info=""> \
        <p class="mediaDescriptionText">Link to map: <a class="gmaplink" target="_blank" rel="external" href="http://www.maps.google.com/?q=' + properties[i].Address +'">Click Here</a>.</p> \
    </li></ul>'));  
}
```

The link is to google maps, but it does not work on mobile version of Safari and Chrome (on mobile devices). I also tried to add an .on() to make sure the click event would be detected:

```
$(document).on('click', '.gmaplink', function(){
    console.log("link working: " + this.href);
    window.open(this.href, '_blank');
});
```

But this code also fails, even though I see that it gets executed with my log (works everywhere other than mobile browsers). However, if I remove the append and simply have the html structure, the links are working on mobile... So this tells me the issue might be with the append.

My question is: what is the proper way to include a link (href) when using append and on mobile browsers.

Thank you!

Comment: Always been a fan of creating individual HTML elements one at a time and appending them to the DOM... I wonder if you take out the backslashes (used to escape double quotes and new lines?) and tried to create the elements individually if you get more stable code?

Comment: What is the structure variable? Are you able to capture the console output from chrome or safari? Can you make a js fiddle with the sample code. The code looks sound, you don't need `.append($(` you can just use `.append( '<ul`

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", do you mean the link does not appear, the link is not clickable, or the link does not get to the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, because you had some weird escape characters when not needed, and you didn't encode the `q` parameter in your URL, and you didn't use the right selector `#structure` :

```
function createStructure(i){

    $('#structure').append($('<ul>' +
    '<li data-type="media" data-url="' + properties[i].image + '" data-target="_blank"></li>' +
    '<li data-thumbnail-path="' + properties[i].thumbnail + '"></li>' +
    '<li data-info="">' +
        '<p class="mediaDescriptionText">Link to map: <a class="gmaplink" target="_blank" rel="external" href="http://www.maps.google.com/?q=' + encodeURIComponent(properties[i].Address) +'">Click Here</a>.</p>' +
    '</li>'+
'</ul>'));

}
```

Edit : Didn't see the question was asked a year ago... =_=